# Node: Bubbling up error response with nested async/await try/catch

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, async-await, try-catch

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly send an Express route handler response from an error generated and caught within nested try/catch blocks.

In the code below, I would like all execution of the route handler to cease if the inner **Try/Catch 3** block catches an error, which will return a **status 404 error**.  At this time, when an error is caught in **Try/Catch 3**, the route handler continues to execute subsequent code in **Code Block A**, catching and return a **status 400** error in **Try/Catch 1**.  The route hanlder then sends this **400 status** response.  How can I have the route handler return the **Try/Catch Block 3 404 response** and, therefore, never execute the code in **Code Block A**?

I've tried modifying return statements in various places, but can't seem to get the route handler to solely return an error caught within the inner **Try/Catch 3**.  Can anybody see, with relative ease, where it is that I'm failing to properly return or manage the propagation of errors?

```
app.get("/endpoint/url", async(req, res) => {
    // Try/Catch 1
    try {

        // Define an async function
        const queryApiFunc = async() => {
            // Try/Catch 3
            try {
                let results = await axios({
                    // Axios Query to API
                })
                if (/*condition is met*/) 
                    throw "No results found";

                }
            catch (e) {
                if (e === "No results found") {
                    res.statusMessage = e;
                    return res.status(404).end();;
                }
            }
        }

        // Try/Catch 2
        try {
            // Call the defined async function
            await queryApiFunc();
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }

        // Code Block A 
        // contains another async call to API 
        // generates 400 status error
        // Code Block A

    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though that's happening because you aren't actually throwing anything from the function.  I'm not entirely sure of exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but what about a structure more like the following ?

```
app.get("/endpoint/url", async(req, res) => {
    const queryApiFunc = async() => {
        let results = await axios({

        });
        if (/*condition is met*/) throw "No results found";
    };

    try {
        await queryApiFunc();
        //Code Block A
    } catch (e) {
        if (e === "No results found") {
            res.statusMessage = e;
            return res.status(404).end();;
        }
    }
});
```

That should get rid of some of the try/catch trapping where you risk swallowing errors and then get you to the actual desired result.